# 3d printing flat pattern

Tags: regions, geometry, polygons, 3d-printing

Four copies of a  flat region defined below ( length AH = 10 mm and prism `Thickness`= 2 mm typically)  is to be 3d printed so that edges LM,KI coincide.

Writing equation of a set all straight lines in the boundary could be cumbersome. How can a multiple `Region` be defined copied on x-axis at 40 mm spacing using a closed  polyline definition like Graphics3D[{x1,y1,0},{x2,y2,0},..] from vertices?

Thanks for all suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here is an attempt at a step by step solution starting from the points in the post by @cvmgt.

```
pts = {{1, 0}, {3, 0}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 3}, {5, 2}, {5, 
    1}, {4, 0}, {5, 0}, {5, -1}, {1, -1}};
reg1 = WindingPolygon[pts];
RegionPlot[reg1]
```

[image]

```
reg2 = Region@TranslationTransform[{4, 0}][reg1];
reg3 = Region@TranslationTransform[{4, 0}][reg2];
reg4 = Region@TranslationTransform[{4, 0}][reg3];
rtot = RegionUnion[reg1, reg2, reg3, reg4];
RegionPlot[DiscretizeRegion@rtot, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Now adding the depth with `RegionProduct`:

```
r3d = RegionProduct[Line[{{0.95}, {1.05}}], DiscretizeRegion@rtot];
RegionPlot3D[r3d]
```

[image]

This can be exported to a STL file for further processing in Meshlab.

```
\[ScriptCapitalR] = MeshRegion[r3d]
Export["C:\\fourregs.stl", \[ScriptCapitalR]]
```

Here is a screenshot in meshlab.

[image]

I would suggest that you scale it in Meshlab for 3D printing purposes. I am not conversant with 3D printing details, so I am afraid, I will have to leave it there.

Comment: Thanks, so overwhelming. Shall get back after noting the details.

Comment: @Narasimham ```r3d = RegionProduct[Line[{{0.90}, {1.1}}], DiscretizeRegion@rtot];```  would give you the correct dimension in Meshlab, but verify it. Scale the polygon side to 10mm in Meshlab and the depth will fall into place at 2mm. Right now, I think it will be 1mm. Watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6psAppbOOXM) video.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean this?

```
pts2 = {{1, 0}, {3, 0}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 3}, {5, 2}, {5, 
    1}, {4, 0}, {5, 0}, {5, -1}, {1, -1}};
pts3 = PadRight[pts2, {Automatic, 3}];
reg = Polygon[pts3];
Graphics3D[reg]
```

[image]

**Edit**

Thanks @Syed provide the example.

```
pts2 = {{1, 0}, {3, 0}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 3}, {5, 2}, {5, 
    1}, {4, 0}, {5, 0}, {5, -1}, {1, -1}};
reg2 = WindingPolygon[pts2];
reg2s = TransformedRegion[reg2, TranslationTransform[{#, 0}]] & /@ {0,
      4, 8, 12} // RegionUnion;
RegionProduct[Line[{{0.}, {1.}}], DiscretizeRegion@reg2s]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes ! Exactly what I meant this. Let me play a little more with it !